# Filter simple products by price

Tags: price, magento-1.8, filter, collection-filtering, simple-product

In my project, I have a requirement where I need to filter **simple products** based on price.

In default Magento, the filtering of price is based on **configurable products**.

Some important points related to my project are:

- The *simple products* in are associated with the *configurable products*.
- Each *configurable product* has three types of *simple products* associated with it.

For example, if the *configurable product* is `A`, then the associated *simple products* are `A1`, `A2` and `A3`.

PS: After failing to hold the grip even after digging deeper in Magento core files, I am asking here.

Please give some clear suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was associating the `simple products` with `configurable products` using a user defined dropdown attribute, `p_type`, which holds three unique numbers which are identification to the associated `simple products`.

While filtering through price, I observed that the url is having a query string as `?price=3000-4999`. I just added the `p_type` attribute to that query string to filter according to the simple products instead of configurable products.

For example,

```
http://mywebsite.com/categoryName/?price=3000-4999&p_type=126
```

This worked for me :)

and also in my case, the simple products were set as `invisible as single product`. So, I did some other changes too.

Comment: this is not work for me